# Redirect after POST request initiated on button

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I made a registration form and depending on successful / unsuccessful registration want to redirect user to the page with notification about it after he clicks the button and receives the response from server. If the registration was successful, route is `"register/success"`, otherwise it is `"register/error"`.

I am sending the request via axios when the button is clicked:

```
<Button
 type="submit"
      onClick={() => {
            sendCreateAccountRequest(
              fullName,
              email,
              password,
              confirmingPassword
            );
          }}
>Create Account</Button>
```

The invoked function:

```
export const sendCreateAccountRequest = (fullName, email, password) => {
  const obj = { fullName, email, password }
  axios
    .post(url.registerUrl, obj)
    .then(response => {
      if (response.status === 200 || response.status === 204) {
        return true
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      if (err.response) {
        return err.message
      }
      if (err.request) {
        return "There are some server troubles"
      }
    })
}
```

I was thinking about using `useHistory` hook, but the invoked function is pure JS and non-react.
As well, I wanted to involve Redux in this, but didn't find a way to use it outside of component as well.

How can I redirect user after submitting the form on the corresponding route? What approach should I use for this purpose?

Answer (score 1):

You may remove the `catch` block from `sendCreateAccountRequest` and handle errors on component level:

```
const history = useHistory();

const handleClick = async () => {
    try {
        await sendCreateAccountRequest(
              fullName,
              email,
              password,
              confirmingPassword
            );
        history.push('register/success');
     } catch (e) {
       // handle error here
       history.push('register/error');
     }
}
(...)

<Button type="submit"onClick={handleClick}>Create Account</Button>
```

However if you would like to delegate that logic outside component, you should have a look at https://redux-toolkit.js.org/ library and it examples.